# C#/WPF - Invoke method every frame

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

**TL;DR: I want to invoke a method every frame.**

I'm creating a connection (represented by a curvy line) between two objects.

[image: Drag a line between two objects.]
The red outlined rectangles are my pins. They can tell when a drag operation starts and ends. Unfortunately they can not receive the **PreviewMouseMove** event as the cursor moves outside. But I want to be able to update the connection end point while dragging.

**MyPin.cs:**

```
private void MyPin_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        return;
    Connection.isDragging = true;
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void MyPin_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        Connection.isDragging = false;
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Therefore I made this workaround by using the **PreviewMouseMove** event of the Canvas.

**MyCanvas.cs**

```
    private void Canvas_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DraggableElement.isDragging)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if(Connection.isDragging)
        {
            Connection.Preview.DragToMouse();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        // a bunch of other else if...
    }
```

However as the project grows in size, workarounds like these become hard to maintain. I do have a better solution in mind, but I don't know how to implement it. I thought of making an update function in **MyPin.cs** class:

```
private void MyPin_Tick()
{
    // Called every frame, do drag logic here.
}
```

But how can I get this method invoked every frame?

Comment: All you need is Mouse.Capture()

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that. It's working. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is capture the mouse with `Mouse.Capture`. Once a control captures the mouse it will continue to receive mouse events even if the mouse exits the control.

```
private void MyPin_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RightButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        return;
    Connection.isDragging = true;
    e.Handled = true;
    Mouse.Capture((IInputElement)sender);
}

private void MyPin_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (isDragging)
    {
        Connection.isDragging = false;
        e.Handled = true;
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
}
```